# Is it possible to restart a level in Red Faction?

Tags: red-faction

In the level where I hitch a ride on a space shuttle, I stupidly initiated the reactor overload immediately, not knowing I had to do more stuff in order to escape. I hit quick save the moment the count down started, and my last save is several hours old.

There's obviously no way I can escape in 20 seconds, so now I'm stuck unless I can restart the map somehow.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. There is a command `level` that is supposed to load a level map but it doesn't work.
You can get closest save from here http://nicouzouf.com/en/?id=redfaction

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I ended up giving up and uninstalling the game... :(